# Using Content.Load<>() in a class that is not derived from Game

Tags: c#, monogame

I have a class (`SpriteManager`) that is not derived from `Game` || `DrawableGameComponent` || `GameComponent` so I use my custom methods.

When my game starts, it runs that class. My question is, how to use `Game.Content.Load` in a class that is not derived from any of the classes above.

I tried declaring a variable in my `SpriteManager` of type `Game` but when I use it, it returns `null` or an `InvalidOperationException`.

My variable `Game`:

```
Game game
```

This is my `LoadContent()` method:

```
spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

//my player sprite
player = new PlayerMovement(game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/collisionPlayer"), game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/" + body[0]), new Vector2(150, 150), new Point(20, 35), 0, new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 11), 2f, 2f, 65f);
```

This is my `SpriteManager` constructor:

```
public SpriteManagerGeneral(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
{
    GraphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;
    LoadContent();

}
```

And this code is in my `Game` class:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(this.GraphicsDevice);
    spriteManager = new SpriteManager(GraphicsDevice);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to have a separate content manager in your spritemanager class, you can create one.

```
ContentManager myManager = new ContentManager(Game.Services, Content.RootDirectory);
```

This way you can handle the load and unload of sprites in your own manager. Note how the 2nd parameter is the path to the content directory, so you can have your own dir if you want.

You can pass the content manager in your constructor:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(this.GraphicsDevice);
    spriteManager = new SpriteManager(GraphicsDevice, Content);
}
```

Comment: I have one question though. I can't use a `ContentManager`. It says that this type could not be found... Do you know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you reference Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content in your class?

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I tried this already in the past but I typed `Microsoft.Xna.Content` instead of `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content` ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the Game instance to the SpriteManager.
For example:

```
class MyGame : Game {
 void LoadContent(ContentManager content){
   ...
   this.spriteManager = new SpriteManager(this);
 }

void Update(...)
void Draw(...)
}
```

Comment: Wich type is `Content` because I can't seem to use `ContentManager` in my `SpriteManager` constructor. I will update my question so you will see what I already have in the `Game` class.

Comment: do you have your class in the same project as the game? have you imported the namespace "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content" ? there is the ContentManager class.

Comment: Yes I forgot the .Framework in `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content`...